# drupal user email

Tags: drupal, mailer

hi i want to know whats the best way for sending newsletter in drupal. And i implemented a module ( user page )for each registered user . how to send the page as newsletter to that user as newsletter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send your own emails in drupal you need to implement [hook_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_mail/6) and then invoke this using [drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_mail/6)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews_scheduler) in the past and for a quick way to email a newsletter nothing I found worked a quickly and easily. However that was a year ago, so there might be more options since I implemented that.